# Java File copy - how to inherit permissions of destination directory

Tags: java, file, copy

When I copy a file from source folder to destination folder the permissions of the destination folder are not inherited by newly copied file. 
is there a way in Java where file copy to destination would inherit permissions of destination folder?

Comment: Which operating system? What permissions exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Windows. I am referring to security permissions like which user can access file and how much access control(read/write etc.) one has

Comment: Such a basic question.  I'm looking for a solution as well. :/

Answer (score 4):

In java7 -  You can do the following

`Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES)`

I have not tested this code. Hope it helps!!

Comment: actually my issue not to copy file permission but to inherit it from the destination folder.

Comment: `COPY_ATTRIBUTES` doesn't work on all file systems. On a macOS, it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Agreed, this is not what's being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Files.Copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) works fine and I tested this code when renameTo() or FileInput/OutputStream code didn't work.

Try without the StandardCopyOption and the permissions of the destination folder are automatically inherited like this:
`Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath());`

Hope it can help.